# Heroku Error: Cannot find module './config/keys'

Tags: node.js, heroku, config

I deployed a Nodejs application, the backend of it so far to Heroku. I am getting an application error in the browser. When I run `heroku logs`, I see this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './config/keys'
```

So I run a `heroku run 'ls -al'` and I see this:

```
Running ls -al on ⬢ murmuring-temple-46226... up, run.3327 (Free)
total 284
drwx------   8 u6811 dyno   4096 Apr 21 11:41 .
drwxr-xr-x  15 root  root   4096 Apr 18 13:09 ..
-rw-------   1 u6811 dyno     21 Apr 21 11:37 .gitignore
drwx------   3 u6811 dyno   4096 Apr 21 11:37 .heroku
drwx------   2 u6811 dyno   4096 Apr 21 11:37 .profile.d
-rw-------   1 u6811 dyno      0 Apr 21 11:37 @1
-rw-------   1 u6811 dyno    574 Apr 21 11:37 index.js
drwx------   2 u6811 dyno   4096 Apr 21 11:37 models
drwx------ 261 u6811 dyno  12288 Apr 21 11:38 node_modules
-rw-------   1 u6811 dyno 235090 Apr 21 11:37 package-lock.json
-rw-------   1 u6811 dyno    565 Apr 21 11:37 package.json
drwx------   2 u6811 dyno   4096 Apr 21 11:37 routes
drwx------   2 u6811 dyno   4096 Apr 21 11:37 services
```

I do see that my `config` folder is not in that list of files and folders up top, but that can be because in my `.gitignore` file, I have it so it will ignore the `keys.js` file, or could it be I have it referenced wrong in my code base?

This is how I require it in `index.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
require('./models/User');
require('./services/passport');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

const app = express();

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [keys.cookieKey]
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

and this is how I reference it in `services/passport.js`:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('../config/keys');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(user => {
    done(null, user);
  });
});

// passport.use() is a generic register to make Passport
// aware of new strategy
// creates a new instance to authenticate users
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback'
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id }).then(existingUser => {
        if (existingUser) {
          // we already have a record with given profile id
          done(null, existingUser);
        } else {
          // we dont have a user record with this id, make a new record
          new User({ googleId: profile.id })
            .save()
            .then(user => done(null, user));
        }
      });
    }
  )
);
```

What is the best practice here for deploying an application successfully to Heroku with a `config/keys.js` folder file structure that houses API keys and other creds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is remove `keys.js` from your `.gitignore` file. Create two other files in your `config` folder. One for development and one for production. Put your keys in the development file and then have `.gitignore` ignore that development file.

Then in your `keys.js` file create an `if` statement like so:

```
// keys.js - figure out what set of credentials to return
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // we are in production - return the prod set of keys
  module.exports = require('./prod');
} else {
  // we are in development - return the dev keys!!
  module.exports = require('./dev');
}
```

Then in your production file you are going to do as my colleague above suggested, but probably more like this:

```
// prod.js - production keys here
module.exports = {
  googleClientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  googleClientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  cookieKey: process.env.COOKIE_KEY
};
```

If you are also connecting to a database like MongoDB then you want to add that as well above like this, `mongoURI: process.env.MONGO_URI`.

The last thing you have to do is make sure all these different environment variables are defined on your Heroku environment variables.

Setting all these things up is straightforward, you just have to know where to look on Herokus’ control interface or do them via command line terminal as my colleague above suggested. If you are pretty comfortable with command line terminal, go ahead and follow the steps above, if not then go inside your browser and navigate to **dashboard.heroku.com**

Find the application you have created for your app, click on it.

Then click on the settings tab and you should see **Config Variables**. Click on reveal Config Variables and that should give you an interface to set up all the different variables you want to add to your application.

One by one you add in a key and its corresponding value

So first do the `GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID`, copy that and enter it as the key, then go grab your credentials. You should already have your credentials copy pasted somewhere.

Do the same for `COOKIE_KEY` and if you are using Mongo, `MONGO_URI

So now you can hide config variables and no one will be able to see them.

As you might imagine you don’t want anyone getting into your heroku account. If someone gets into your heroku account, I don’t know what to tell you.

Now you can deploy your application by committing your code using git and deploy it using git as well.

Do a `git status` that shows your files and folders.

`git add .`

`git commit -m “completed environment variables”`

`git push`

`git push heroku master`

You should be good to go after this with that error having gone away.

Answer (score 1):

You do the right thing by ignoring the configuration file.You should always keep away your secret keys from github and bitbucket. The right way in this situation is to set your keys as an environment variables on heroku. You can use these commands:

```
# Add new variable
heroku config:set COOKIE_KEY=somekey

# Remove variable
heroku config:unset COOKIE_KEY

# Get all environment variables
heroku config

# Get environment variable by name
heroku config:get COOKIE_KEY
```

In your application, you can access these variables using `process.env` object:

```
process.env.COOKIE_KEY
process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
```

Note: the configuration keys must be in uppercase